# Prove that $S^2 \times S^2$ is obtained by attaching a 4-cell to $S^2 ∨ S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have to work with the definition **(for attaching an n-cell to a topological space X)** to be the push-out of the following diagram : [image]

Now, The question :

> Prove that $S^2 × S^2$ is obtained by attaching a 4-cell to $S^2∨S^2$

My attempt:

So I have the following diagram :
[image]

> My aim : Consider $X$ to the push-out of the diagram and then show that it's homeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^2$ .

From $S^2∨S^2$ to $S^2 \times S^2$ we take the inclusion.

And consider, $g : D^4 \to S^2 \times S^2$ by, $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=((\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2}},\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2}}),(\frac{x_3}{\sqrt{{x_3}^2+{x_4}^2} },\frac{x_4}{\sqrt{{x_3}^2+{x_4}^2}} ))$

Then, by definition of Push-out we have that $\exists$ continuous map $h : X \to S^2 \times S^2$. Commuting diagram gives that $h$ must be surjective (since, $g$ is clearly surjective).

Now, if I can show that $h$ is injective, then we are done , since $X$ is compact and $S^2 \times S^2$ is Hausdorff.

> So how to prove that $h$ is injective?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The map $g$ you give is not injective.  For example all choices of $x_1,x_3$ give the same value $g(x_1,0,x_3,0) = ((1,0),(1,0))$.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure what the image of $g$ is supposed to be, since your coordinates for $S^2$ are unclear.  It seems you might be using $S^1$ instead.

Comment: I never said that g is injective. I only said that g is surjective. Please read carefully.

Comment: Anyway, if you can give an alternative argument, that will also be appreciated.

Comment: $g$ should at least be injective on the interior of $D^4$ (you are right it does not need to be injective on the boundary)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline:

Let $p: D^2 \to S^2$ be the obvious projection collapsing the boundary $D^2$ to a marked point point $*$.  Then write $D^4 = D^2 \times D^2$.  Embed $S^2 \vee S^2 \subset S^2 \times S^2$ as $(S^2 \times \{*\}) \cup (\{*\} \times S^2)$.  The map you want to use is $g(x,y) \to (p(x),p(y))$ for $(x,y) \in D^2 \times D^2$.  It is easy to show this is injective on the interior of $D^4$.  For example, if $x \not = x'$ are two distinct points in the interior of $D^2$, then $p(x) \not = p(x')$ so $g(x,y) \not = g(x',y')$.  You can also show that the images of $D^4$ and $S^2 \vee S^2$ only intersect in the images of $S^3$, so these are identified by the pushout, and injectivity of $h$ will follow.

Comment: So in your answer, $p$ is the map that is identity on the interior of $D^2 $ and maps the entire boundary to a single marked point?

Comment: But how does it take care of surjectivity?

Comment: @Coherent $g$ is the product of two surjective maps, so it is surjective.

Comment: Sorry but I'm facing a bit difficulty in understanding. Can you please give $p$ explicitly, then that will clear everything.

Comment: @Coherent Your interpretation was correct.  An explicit map can be obtained by stereographic projection if needed, but it shouldn't be needed.  $p$ is the 2-cell map for $S^2$ in the cell decomposition with a single 0-cell and a single 2-cell.